# Examples of small multiplicative subgroups of BIG quotient rings of the gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, gaussian-integers

### Setup:

One can study the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ by looking at its quotient rings $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ often called "the Integers mod K". These quotient rings contain multiplicative subgroups that can sometimes have very small exponent,

A striking example is the multiplicative subgroup of the integers modulo 24, which we denote as $ \left( \mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z} \right)^\times$.  This group has only 8 elements contained in it, and very remarkably it has exponent 2. Meaning that for any element $a \in \left( \mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z} \right)^\times, a^2 = 1$

Yet the original ring has 24 elements in it, which is a whole lot more than 2. By studying the [Carmichael Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) one can uncover other numerical gold where a VERY big ring contains a multiplicative subgroup with a very small exponent. (For example $ \left( \mathbb{Z}/240\mathbb{Z} \right)^\times $ where the original ring has 240 elements and yet the exponent here is only 4).

I'm interested in finding the bigger finite-commutative-rings whose multiplicative subgroups have very small exponents.

### Question:

If we turn our attention to the gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and look at quotient rings $R$. What is an example of the LARGEST finite quotient ring whose multiplicative subgroup has exponent 2?

Answer (score 1):

- Any quotient of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ other than $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(1+i)$ and $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(2)$ contains the cyclic group $1,i,-1,-i$ so its multiplicative group won't be of exponent $2$.
- To determinate the group structure of $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(3^m)^\times$  we go to the $p$-adic integers ($p=3$), starting with $\Bbb{Z}_p^\times=\langle \zeta_{p-1}\rangle (1+p)^{\Bbb{Z}_p}$ to obtain $\Bbb{Z}_3[i]^\times=\langle \zeta_8\rangle (1+3)^{\Bbb{Z}_3}(1+3i)^{\Bbb{Z}_3}$ and $$\Bbb{Z}[i]/(3^m)^\times=\Bbb{Z}_3[i]/(3^m)^\times=\langle \zeta_8\rangle  (1+3)^{\Bbb{Z/3^{m-1}Z}}(1+3i)^{\Bbb{Z/3^{m-1}Z}}$$

  The case $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$ is easier
  $$ \Bbb{Z}[i]/((2+i)^m)^\times=\Bbb{Z}_5/((2+i)^m)^\times=\Bbb{Z}_5/(5^m)^\times=\Bbb{Z}/(5^m)^\times= \langle \zeta_4\rangle (1+5)^{\Bbb{Z/5^{m-1}Z}}$$

From this and that Z[i] is a PID where p splits iff p≡3mod4 we know the group structure of  $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(a)^\times$ for all $a$.

Comment: I have a series of questions: 1. What does the notation $\langle \zeta_{p-1} \rangle$ mean exactly, because in the case of p = 3 $\langle \zeta_{p-1} \rangle \ne \langle \zeta_{2} \rangle $ but rather $\langle \zeta_{8} \rangle$ [ I know that the exponent of the multiplicative subgroup group of $\mathbb{Z[i]}/3$ is 8, so i can guess there's a connection here]. 2. What does the expression $(1+p)^{\mathbb{Z}_p}$ mean here exactly? My best guess after consulting a lot of online materials is it refers to the multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/3^{m-1}$ generated by powers of that element?